# Pandas changes date format while reading csv file altough format in the file does not change

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that I don't understand with reading a csv file using pandas. Pandas suddenly changes the format of the date altough the format in the file is exactly the same. Here you can see the screenshot of the file, once opened with Excel, once with Windows-Editor, and once after Pandas has read it in Sypder.

[image]

You can see that the date format remains the same in Excel and the CSV file but when Pandas reads it, it suddently changes it by switching the order of months and days.

Here is the code I use:

```
import pandas as pd

pathOfTheInputData = "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Test_Read_Date.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(pathOfTheInputData, sep=';', header=0, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, index_col=['datetime'])
```

And here you can have a look at the data: [Test_Data](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/e5wEqbM4#link)

Any idea why this is happening? I also tried it by setting `infer_datetime_format=False` but this leads to the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True` as parameter of `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Test_Read_Date.csv', sep=';',
                 parse_dates=['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)
```

Output

```
>>> df

               timestamp  temperatures
0    2021-06-07 22:00:00         17.00
1    2021-06-07 22:15:00         16.88
2    2021-06-07 22:30:00         16.75
3    2021-06-07 22:45:00         16.63
4    2021-06-07 23:00:00         16.50
...                  ...           ...
9699 2021-09-16 22:45:00         13.25
9700 2021-09-16 23:00:00         13.40
9701 2021-09-16 23:15:00         13.33
9702 2021-09-16 23:30:00         13.25
9703 2021-09-16 23:45:00         13.18

[9704 rows x 2 columns]

>>> df.loc[487:488]
              timestamp  temperatures
487 2021-06-12 23:45:00         18.38
488 2021-06-13 00:00:00         18.30
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it works when using `df = pd.read_csv(pathOfTheInputData, sep=';', header=0, dayfirst=True, low_memory=False, infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, index_col=['datetime'])`, but I don't understand why in my original code Pandas suddently changes the format altough the data format in the csv file remains the same. The weird thing is that I have several similar datasets. For some of them, everything works fine with the code from above but for others, I get the same problem. I don't understand why it seems to be undeterministic.

Comment: @PeterBe : It seems that there are many more locations where the data format is not correctly guessed by pandas, see at iloc[8]. Lesson learnt: we must always specify the value for `dayfirst`.